# How to return a string without the first character using an array

Tags: java, arrays, string

How do I return a string e.g. H4321 but return the numbers only, not the H. I need to use an array. So far I have:

```
char [] numbers = new char[5];
return numbers;
```

Assuming I need a line between those two. String is called value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substring` method on `String` object.

Like this:
`String newValue = value.substring(1);`

and then call: `char[] charArray = newValue.toCharArray();`

Another solution - it copies old array without first element. :

`char[] newNumbers = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, 1, numbers.length);`

Comment: Yeah I knew how to do that, but is there a way to do it using an array? So that it would work for any similar string e.g. G6789

Answer (score 1):

Use the code bellow:

```
public String getNumber(){
    char [] numbers = new char[5];
    numbers = new String("H4321").toCharArray();

    String result = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length ; i++){
        if(Character.isDigit(numbers[i])){
            result += numbers[i];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```